# SLAM - odometry motion model

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, odometry, movement

I am making a project with a 4 wheeled differential robot to make visual SLAM using a stereo rig. I have some encoders to measure de displacement and the steering angle of the robot and I want to use the **odometry motion model** in the fastSLAM algorithm.

To use the odometry motion model you need to calculate the values it needs from the odometry reading (incremental encoders), $u_t=(\bar{x}_{t-1},\bar{x_t})$ where $\bar{x}_{t-1}=(\bar{x}\>\bar{y}\>\bar{\theta})$ and $\bar{x}_t=(\bar{x}'\>\bar{y}'\>\bar{\theta}')$ are the previous and the current pose extracted from the odometry of the vehicle.

My question is about how to obtain those values from the encoders. I guess that in this case I would need to obtain the equations from the geometric model for the differential robot:

$D_L=\frac{2\cdot\pi \cdot R_L}{N_c}\cdot N_L$

$D_R=\frac{2\cdot\pi \cdot R_R}{N_c}\cdot N_R$

$D_T=\frac{D_L+D_R}{2}$

$\Delta\theta=\frac{D_L-D_R}{L}$

where $D_L$ is the advance of the left wheel, $D_R$ is the advance of the right wheel, $R_L$ is the lecture from the left encoder, $R_R$ the lecture from the right encoder, $N_C$ the total number of pulses of the encoder type, $D$ is the total distance achieved by the robot and $\theta$ the angle steered. $L$ is the distance between the wheels.

Using those equations is possible to obtain the pose in every time step:

$\bar{x}_{t}=\bar{x}_{t-1}+D\cos(\theta_{t-1})$

$\bar{y}_{t}=\bar{y}_{t-1}+D\sin(\theta_{t-1})$

$\bar{\theta}_{t}=\bar{\theta}_{t-1}+\Delta\theta$

So those last are the values I need to inject to the modometry motion model and then add gaussian noise to them.
Am I right? Or is there another way of computing the pose from odometry for a differential 4-wheel robot?

Comment: Are you trying to *simulate* motion, or are you trying to get position and heading from actual data? What do you mean when you say "steering angle"? Does this vehicle use differential or Ackermann steering?

Comment: I am trying o get position and heading from odometry to use it inside the odometry motion model in SLAM. With steering angle I mean that I could compute the angle $\Delta\theta$ from the encoders. It is a differential 4-wheel robot.